# How can one prove the permutation rule rigorously?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Let $(s_1,  s_2,  \ldots, s_n)$ be a sequence of $n$ elements. What is the number of permutations  of this sequence?

Intuitively, this is really obvious: For the first position of our permutation we have $n$ choices,  for the second we have $n-1$ choices because we already used one element, ... which yields $n!$.

Since the solution to this question makes use of the product rule in combinatorics, which itself is defined using sets, I was seeking for a more rigorous proof of this permutation  formula. The question is equivalent to the number of injections $f: \{s_1, s_2, \ldots, s_n\} \to \{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$ but counting those requires a similar argumentation to the intuitive argument above. I understand that at each stage, the element we pick for the position $j$ in our sequence depends on the previous choices, but the number of such choices doesn't. Could someone maybe provide a more rigorous proof for the permutation rule (maybe using sets)?

**Edit:** Here is what I came up with using the solution provided by Henry.

**Base case:** For $n = 1$ the formula vacuously holds.

**Induction Hypothesis:** Given a sequence of $n$ distinct elements, the number of permutations of those elements  is given by $n!$.

**Inductive step $(n \to n+1)$:** Let $x= n!$ be the number of permutations of the sequence  $(s_1, s_2, \ldots, s_n)$ and suppose we wanted to find the number of permutations of the sequence $(s_1, s_2, \ldots,  s_{n+1})$. One can create a permutation of this new sequence by considering a permutation of the sequence $(s_1, s_2, \ldots, s_n)$ and adding to it the element $s_{n+1}$, whereby we have $n+1$ possible positions where $s_{n+1}$ could be placed. Since we do this for every permutations of the sequence $(s_1, s_2, \ldots, s_n)$ we obtain $(n+1) \cdot n! = (n+1)!$.

Comment: Define "more rigorous." The basic counting argument works fine.

Comment: Take a permutation of $n$ elements, and create a permutation of $n+1$ elements buy inserting the new element into one of $n+1$ positions.   Use induction to show the count is factorial.

Comment: Why does the product rule bother you? If the product rule is defined 'rigorously' using sets and leads to the number of permutations, what do you see goes wrong?

Comment: The case with distinct elements is not the same as when some are repeated. You takr it into account in your "induction hypothesis" however it is not mentioned in the question at the beginning of the post. So does the distinct case with $n!$ satisfies you, or do you want us to help you study also the general situation with repeated terms ?